# Uncaught (in promise): nav controller was destroyed

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2

i'm trying to do `this.navCtrl.setRoot(page);`
i faced this error :

> Uncaught (in promise): nav controller was destroyed

anyone knows why ?

Comment: using `this.rootPage = page` instead of `this.navCtrl.setRoot(page);` should fix your problem.

Comment: where are you calling this? Ca you show the full method? can you post your `ionic info` output?

Answer (score 0):

using `this.rootPage = page;` instead of `this.navCtrl.setRoot(page);` should fix your problem.

Comment: should have been a comment

Comment: @Faisal i don't have 50 reputation... so cant add one.

Comment: @Faisal no problem :)

Answer (score 0):

This will work for you.

```
 this.app.getRootNav().setRoot(LoginPage).then(() => {
      this.app.getRootNav().popToRoot();
 });
```