# Ionic 2 nav controller was destroyed

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

```
this.app.getRootNav().setRoot(LoginPage)
```

> Error : nav controller was destroyed

Whenever its called its shows error.
Lots of people reported the same issue but there is no specific and exact answer to solve that.I am struggling with this issue since last 3 day.

Comment: Can you show the page where you use it? more code?

Comment: this is a duplicate of this issue; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45562569/uncaught-in-promise-nav-controller-was-destroyed